# Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055.Selenium 3 & Firefox 38.6.0

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am getting the below error message while opening firefox browser with Selenium 3.I tried downgrading to Selenium 2.46 but still I get the same error. Browser is opened by the script, but its going to catch block after some time.

Firefox version : 38.6.0
Selenium 2.46 (Also tried with 3 as well)
Mozilla exe path : "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

Error message :

```
 Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. 
Firefoxconsole output:on move on file 
C:\Users\D828737\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous2231645626157870160webdriver-  
profile\sessionstore-backups\recovery.js (Access is denied.)
```

Comment: Your `Firefox` version is quite outdated. Try to upgrade to `v49`

Answer (score 1):

If you **need** This Firefox version specifically, I'd try bumping the Selenium version until it works, e.g. 2.47.0, 2.47.1 till 2.53.0. See releases [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases?after=selenium-2.51.0). If you look at the [Firefox release](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/38.0/releasenotes/) date and the Selenium release date, you'll see you need something that was released around August 2015 ~ Selenium 2.47.1.

If the version doesn't matter, update your Firefox to the latest version, and use latest Selenium (3.0.1 for the time being), and additionally you'll need to download [GeckoDriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and specify the path to it, [like you do](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/launching-firefox-browser-with-geckodriver-selenium-3) for ChromeDriver.